# Why some of our smart groups are empty after CiviCRM upgrade?

Tags: smartgroups

We upgrade recently from 4.5.8 to 4.6.6 on our CiviCRM instances.

After that we note that some smart groups become empty. An example as proof:

**Smart group has been emptied:**

> Event type = Centre Obert ...and...
>
> Start Date - greater than or equal to "september 12th, 2013 12:00 AM" ...and...
>
> End Date - less than or equal to "juny 20th, 2014 11:59 PM" ...and...
>
> Participant Status ID is Inscrit ...and...
>
> Participant Role is 1

NOTE: Cleaning caches and rebuilding smart groups has not worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the ideal solution but so far has worked.

1. Edit the search criteria for the affected/s smart group/s *- The search result remain empty*
2. Search again - *The search result will be good*
3. Update the smart group

After this the smart/s group/s works correctly again.